# Dividing all elements in a single row of a DataFrame by an element in another column in that same row and then do this for all rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization

Say I have a simple dataframe as below and I want to take the ith element in `column_4` and divide it into the ith elements in all of the other columns (except `column_4`) for that particular row and then perform this on all rows.

Another way of saying it is how do I normalize columns 1, 2, 3 by column 4? Is there an easy way of doing this?

*E.g*

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[1,2,3], 'column_2':[4,5,6], 'column_3':[7,8,9], 'column_4':[2,3,4]})
df.head()
```

**Desired Output**

```
df2 = pd.Dataframe({'column_1':[1/2,2/3,3/4], 'column_2':[4/2,5/3,6/4], 'column_3':[7/2,8/3,9/4], 'column_4':[2,3,4]})
df2.head()
```

Notice each element in `column_1,column_2,column_3`  has been divided by its equivalent element in `column_4`.

**Note:** In this case I have used a relatively small DataFrame however was also wondering whether there is a way to generalize the result for a DataFrame that has say 1000's of rows and 100's of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You can simply do

```
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'] / df['column_4']
```

and so on

The operations are vectorized as in numpy

If you want a new dataframe do

```
In [18]: import pandas as pd
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':[1,2,3], 'column_2':[4,5,6], 'column_3':[7,8,9], 'column_4
    ...: ':[2,3,4]})
    ...: df.head()
Out[18]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0         1         4         7         2
1         2         5         8         3
2         3         6         9         4

In [19]: new_df = pd.DataFrame()

In [20]: for col in ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']:
    ...:     new_df[col] = df[col] / df['column_4']
    ...:

In [21]: new_df
Out[21]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3
0  0.500000  2.000000  3.500000
1  0.666667  1.666667  2.666667
2  0.750000  1.500000  2.250000
```

### Option 2

As pointed out by anky, you could solve this in a one liner like this:

```
df.drop('column_4',1).div(df['column_4'],axis=0)
```